# How to present a DataTable which presents options o edit existing records that are returned from an AJAX get call and also addition of a new record

Tags: datatables

Datatable - table1 is populated with records from an ajax GET response.
I want the option to "edit" existing records and "add" new records from the UI.

Issue 1: I am able to add a new record to the HTML view successfully, but when the user clicks on submit, the attempt to access the new record fails in DataTable() functions. How to resolve this?

Issue 2: How to access hidden column values for existing as well as new records in the DataTable?

Comment: This question is very broad - you should try to focus on one specific issue you are facing. It helps if you also show what you have tried as a [mre].

Comment: If you have not already done so, you should take the [tour] and read [ask].